Buffer() Deprecation warning trying to run any NodeJS script under IIS
I've read over all of the related Buffer() deprecation threads but still don't have a solution for my situation.
I have NodeJS installed on a Windows server and have it connectd to IIS via iisnode, urlrewrite, etc, etc using reverse proxy.  When I go to run the app, I get the error about Buffer() being deprecated.  Thing is, the code I'm running is simply this:
console.log("hi")
I have the following packages installed:
express
fs
http
path
readline
url
So I'm wondering if one of those packages is to blame.  I'm a complete noob at NodeJS and such so I'm totally lost here... what steps to take, etc.  It doesn't help that the server I'm trying to run this on isn't allowed to download stuff from the internet.  If I want to add packages, I have to download them elsewhere and copy them over (via slow vpn).
In any case, if one of those packages is at fault, what's the fix?  Thank you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please, show the exact error instead of describing it. And it's impossible to help with such warning without having https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This is specific to your app and whatever happens in it. It can possibly be fixed by updating dependencies. There's no problem per se as currently such warning doesn't affect anything, and this can last for many years

The iisnode is very much deprecated since 2016 when HttpPlatformHandler cames out, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/


In any case, if one of those packages is at fault, what's the fix?

This is because the iisnode module itself is using the Buffer() method, you may need to update the Interceptor.js file. Simply refer to this thread:https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues/60
If you simply don't want to see these warning messages, you can disable them via configuration. Something like:
<iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="your/path/to/node.exe --no-deprecation --no-warnings"/>

